# getXmlHttpRequest() не работает

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Добрый вечер, по какой такой причине браузеры могут ругаться на getXmlHttpRequest() ?

В логе хрома вот что пишется: Uncaught ReferenceError: getXmlHttpRequest is not defined

Код вот такой, пытался с помощью ajax вытащить из заголовков передеваемым php файлом текущее время:

```
function getTime(){
    req = getXmlHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(req.readyState==4){
            var time=req.getResponseHeader('Current');
            var res=document.getElementById('result');
            res.firstChild.nodeValue=time;
        }
    }
    req.open("HEAD","getTimeFile.php",true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

Содержимое php файла getTimeFile.php:

```
<?php
header('Current: '.date("H:i:s"));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хм, тут толи я вася, толи это действительно ф-ция и ее нужно пропускать только через обьявленную ф-цию. Заметка тем кто столкнется с такой же проблемой, обьявите вот эту ф-цию:

```
function getXmlHttpRequest(){
try {
    return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (ee) {
    }
}
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
}
```

Comment: Ну, как бы, да, это не стандартная функция браузера. [http://www.jstoolbox.com/2008/02/08/sozdanie-obekta-xmlhttprequest/][1]

[1]:http://www.jstoolbox.com/2008/02/08/sozdanie-obekta-xmlhttprequest/